# How to deploy Trusty TEE?

Tags: android-kernel, trusted-computing, android-rom

Recently, I'm studying Trust Execution Environment. And finding that Android has implemented a TEE os called Trusty. I followed the instruction on https://source.android.com/security/trusty/ and built the Trusty system. But how can I deploy it? Or simply run it?

Comment: hi, I'm facing the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Comment: I found an alternative project named optee, which is an open source implementation of TEE environment. It supports Optee+AOSP for the hikey board, but as for other devices, it'll have  to be ported.

Comment: @logan_white how did you do it?

Comment: @LenaBru Sorry, I gave up.